# How to add a Field of Task to Task Remainder pop up window

Tags: admin

Here the requirement is to add a field into a Task Remainder pop up window[image: In the below pop window we have to add some extra fields which we can see while creating Task.Please assist on this...]

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation currently Salesforce has. The idea has been created for the same but there is not a single comment from salesforce and currently, it is in product team review.

Summary of idea:-

> Salesforce should enable administrators to customize the fields
>   displayed in the reminder pop-up window.
>
> The purpose would be to eliminate the additional number of clicks and
>   page views a user needs to make to get all of the data he or she needs
>   to complete the specified task.

Refer here:- [Enable Customization of the Reminder Pop-Up Window](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HB98AAG)

Comment: Hello sanket Thank you for your response......can't we do this by Apex or triggers ???

Comment: via triggers, you can send email reminders. The same can be done via process builder and flow.

Comment: Thank you for your response,,,,,,,,can you give me an idea how to do via Process Builder....or send me a link shows the same task

Comment: https://automationchampion.com/tag/email-notification-for-task-using-process-builder/

Comment: hello sanket I am not looking for email notification...i want to add a field in pop up wiindow of Task